# addFieldToFilter() with OR Condition in magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection, filter

```
$collectionData = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(['attribute1', 'attribute2'],
        [
            ['in' => $attribute1],
            ['nin' => $attribute2],
        ]);
```

I want to get collection based on "OR condition" on three attribute for example a product which has color yellow or size small but not manufacture china.

Comment: is this collection is EAV collection or flat  collection

Comment: getting data from product collection

Comment: use `addAttributeToFilter()` instead of `addFieldToFilter`

Answer (score 34):

I assume that in your example, yellow, small and china are options in dropdowns.
You will need their ids first, but let's assume the are `$yellowId`, `$smallId` and `$chinaId`.

You can try this filtering.

```
->addFieldToFilter(['color', 'size', 'country'],
    [
        ['eq' => $yellowId],
        ['eq' => $smallId],
        ['neq' => $chinaId]
    ]);
```

Comment: You can also see `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addFilterByRequiredOptions` for an example with a single attribute.

Comment: Marius, you are a saint of the Magento universe

Answer (score 12):

Try this, It work for me

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter([
     ['attribute' => 'attribute1','null' => true ],
     ['attribute' => 'attribute1','gteq' => 1 ]
]);
    // Don't change 'attribute', It will be used at AbstractCollection: 373
    // WHERE attribute1 = NULL OR attribute1 >= 1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why, but this filter doesn't work for me: [
['attribute' => 'sku','nlike' => '%test123%' ],
['attribute' => 'sku','nlike' => '%test234%' ],
]

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @hallleron maybe you need to re-check your data, I have a quick check on Magento 2.3.5-p2. It's still work perfectly

Comment: @hallleron  print_r($collection->getSelectSql(true));  you can use this to check your query first.  Make sure your collection is newly created by the factory and carefully by the filters added before

Answer (score 6):

This should give you all items that are not made in china and that have either color yellow or size small:

```
$collection
    ->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer', ['neq' => $chinaId])
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        ['color', 'size'],
        [
            ['eq' => $yellowId],
            ['eq' => $smallId]
        ]
);
```

Answer (score 6):

I know the original question has been answered before, but if you want to add OR condition to a simple field to a flat collection, this is the correct way to do it:

```
$this->addFieldToFilter(
    'published_date', 
    [
        [
            'lteq' => date('Y-m-d H:m:i')
        ], 
        [
            'null' => true
        ], 
        [
            'from' => '9999-01-01 00:00:00',
            'to' => '9999-12-31 23:59:59',
        ]
    ]
);
```

just for reference: this will appear in the query as `((published_date <= '2020-03-24 18:03:57') OR (published_date IS NULL))`

of course, you can add as many conditions to the array if follow the correct pattern. Also be sure that using from and to conditions, those are need to be in the same array as above

Comment: Thanks!! it helped me

Answer (score 4):

From the description of the method: `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection::addAttributeToFilter` which is the same with `addFieldToFilter` method from the same class.
Product entity is implemented with EAV.

```
// If $attribute is an array will add OR condition with following format:
array(
   array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>'test%'),
   array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>'test%'),
)
public function addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition = null, $joinType = 'inner')
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is the only method that worked form me

Comment: Aaron Allen answer did not work for me, the above did.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $collection->addFieldToFilter(['status','status'],[['nin'=>$allnonactiveorderstatus],['null'=>true]])
```